# Socket Read \n at the End From Java Client

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Using below code I reading data from socket. On the other side the Java client sending string data. But while reading the data an additional \n appears at the end of the string. Can anyone explain why this happen.

**Code:**

```
  unsigned char buf[100]; 
  rd=read(newsockfd,buf,100);
  char cmd[30];
  sprintf(cmd,"%s",buf);
```

**Result:**

```
buf->"DATA\n"
cmd->"DATA\n"
```

From the client if I sent "DATA" then I am getting "DATA\n" at the server side. Can anyone explain the reason for this ? and how can I extract the exact data I sent.

Comment: Could it be that the Java client on the other side adds newline at the end of the data it sends ? I could easily imagine a function like `sendLine()` that takes a `String` as a parameter and decides on its own to add a newline at the end.

Comment: What if you initialize both buffers to null characters on the C side?

Comment: @ ereOn Yes I am using println("str"), that might be the cause. Thank you very much for the valuable information.

Comment: Now @ereOn should turn the comment into an answer, and Haris should accept that answer :)

Comment: @Dialecticus: You are correct, even if, in the end, my "answer" is only a blind guess. Anyway, I wrote an answer. Thanks.

Comment: `println()` sends the data along with a line terminator, as the Javadoc says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here would be that the newline comes from the Java client itself.

Probably the client is using a function like `sendLine(String)` or something that **adds a newline to the string passed to it before sending it on the network**. I don't know Java but this seems very likely.

Answer (score 1):

In java you can say (as other people has pointed) socket.writeLine("Data") which appends a "\n" at the end.
One thing I've noticed though, in the code you wrote, there is a possibly error you could get, if the sender sends you more than 100 chars you would get a memory error.

```
unsigned char buf[100];   
rd=read(newsockfd,buf,1024);
```

Here you say you want to read up to 1024 chars/bytes but the buffer is declared as [100], be careful!

Comment: Thanks for noticing me that bug, but I at the client side I am sending maximum of 20 bytes